# Variable not parsed as string

Tags: android

Well in my onActivityResult() method, i have a switch case condition like this:

```
 if (resultList.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("Hi")){

             Random random = new Random();
             int numberOfMethods = 4;

             switch(random.nextInt(numberOfMethods)) {
                 case 0: 
                     String txthow = "Hi "+ data.toString()";
                     tts.speak(txthow, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                     break;
                 case 1: 
                     String txthowdue = "How are you "+data.toString()+"?";
                     tts.speak(txthowdue, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                     break;

             }
```

When my TTS repeat the `data` value it repeats something like `intent\00n` or anyway something not correct because that value would be for example a name `David`. i also declared `private String data;` but nothing change.

Comment: Please share all relevant code.

Comment: what do you mean? this is the part of code. if the resultList contains "Hi" there are 2 possible answers. `data` is a variable that you can insert from a edittext. If i write in the edittext `david` the TTS it should answer for example `Hi david`.

Comment: data is usually the name of the Intent. The third parameter of onActivityResult. Why are you expecting something different?

Comment: ooooh, my bad!!! i have only change the variable name right?

Comment: Out of curiosity,Just see the statement `resultList.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("Hi")`. In this, `toLowerCase()` returns a `String` with all small characters. but you are comparing it with the String `Hi` where the first letter `H` is a capital. How this condition will be `true` then? Is it your typo error?

Comment: @GopalRao i get no errors there

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

**public String toString()**

> Returns a string representation of the
>   object. In general, the toString method returns a string that
>   "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but
>   informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is
>   recommended that all subclasses override this method. The toString
>   method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the
>   class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@',
>   and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the
>   object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the
>   value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

This means that `toString()` will return a String representation of the `Object`. In this case it is an `Intent` object. What is probably returning is a String with the name of the `Class` and its location in memory.

What you want to do is to get the desired value from the `Intent` using one of its `getX()`.